# Offlineimap: python code to read refresh token from unix pass (or gpg file)

Tags: python, password, offlineimap

I use offlineimap to organize my emails, and in order to use my work account I am now obliged to use OAuth2 authentication.

I successfully got a refresh-token, and thus offlineimap works if I set the variable `oauth2_refresh_token` accordingly. However, I would like to store the refresh token encrypted (I use unix pass, that stores it as a gpg encrypted file).

I cannot manage to use the `oauth2_refresh_token_eval` to set a python code that reads the refresh token from pass, or the corresponding gpg file, probably because of my complete lack of python knowledge. I tried to use the same code as for `remotepasseval` (and that for the latter works perfectly):

```
def get_pass(account): 
       return check_output("pass email/" + account, shell=True).splitlines()[0]
```

but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

and in fact the offlineimaprc template here specifies that the returned values by `oauth2_refresh_token_eval` "must be bytes" (whatever this means).

What is the correct code to use in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
def get_token(account):
    return check_output("pass " + account, shell=True).decode().splitlines()[0]
```